# What is KEY generally refers to in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have copied the create statement to clipboard. Its showing

Key portion:

PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
  KEY `contID` (`contID`)

What does the KEY refers to and What type of KEY it is?

Comment: can you paste whole create statement? Which version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

`KEY` creates an index (or key) on the column for faster look up on that column in queries.  Generally you would use `KEY` on a column that is used in joins and `WHERE` clauses.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 2):

From [13.1.14. CREATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html)

> {INDEX|KEY}

KEY is a synonym for INDEX

[8.3.2. Using Primary Keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html)

> The **PRIMARY KEY** for a table represents the column or set of columns
>   that you use in your most vital queries. It has an associated index,
>   for fast query performance.